# How to calculate the tolerance of Newton method with Gaussian elimination

Tags: python, math, gaussian

Based on the Newton Raphson method for multivariable functions, the tolerance δ is calculated as follows:

*J*(*x*) · δ = −*F*(*x*)

where *J* is a 2×2 matrix (Jacobian matrix), δ is the tolerance that is calculated by the Gaussian elimination method, and *F* is a 2×1 matrix (initial given function).

How can I calculate the tolerance using the Gaussian elimination method knowing both the Jacobian and given function as seen in the equation above?

Comment: python doesn't have build-in matrix stuff, so no.

Comment: any idea how I can perform this operation then ? Or is there another way to obtain the tolerance using some sort of built in function?

Comment: Invert the J(x) matrix, of course.  You can even write it out by hand - not complicated: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse.html